# Create Custom Product Details Page for specific category in Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.3, magento2.3.4

I want to create custom product details page for specific category ? how to i'll do this or 'll override catalog_product_view.xml ?

Please share any help.

Thanks